# Breaking changes in gsoap (updating version from 2.8.8 to 2.8.16)

Tags: c++, xml, web-services, wsdl, gsoap

I have a C++ client using gSoap. When it used 2.8.8 version of gSoap it worked well. After upgrade to 2.8.16 it stopped working. It seems the problem is the following: we are missing soap envelope. Old version sent:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="urn:attachmentSoapServer"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<data here>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

New version is sending only:

```
<data here>
```

How to add soap header like it was in old version?

The code is like this:

```
struct soap soap;    
soap_init(&soap);

soap_call_here(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the wsdl2h warning messages and the generated .h interface file.

To ensure SOAP transport, the generated .h file should have:

```
//gsoap ns1 service transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
```

and for each service operation we would expect something like:

```
//gsoap ns1 service method-protocol:   method SOAP
```

If the method-protocol is HTTP (or POST,GET,PUT) then REST without SOAP Envelope and without SOAP Body will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the namespace be defined in **XXXBinding.h**, which is auto generated by soapcpp2.exe like below? Or it must be changed in your code.

```
    MyServiceSoap12Binding()
    { 
        soap = soap_new(); 
        if (soap && !soap->namespaces) 
        {
            static const struct Namespace namespaces[] = 
            {
                {"SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "http://www.w3.org/*/soap-envelope", NULL},
                {"SOAP-ENC", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "http://www.w3.org/*/soap-encoding", NULL},
                {"xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.w3.org/*/XMLSchema-instance", NULL},
                {"xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "http://www.w3.org/*/XMLSchema", NULL},
                //...
                {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}
            };
        soap->namespaces = namespaces;
        }
    }
```